# jQuery issue with editing heading tags using html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have a load of H1 H2 and H3 tags on a website and I want to be able to put a `span` around PART of these heading tags.

At the moment I have this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

            // get all headings first
            jQuery('h1, h2, h3').each(function(){
                // get the text
                var theHtml = jQuery(this).html();
                // split by spaces
                var theWords = theHtml.split(" ");
                // count the words
                var wordCount = theWords.length;
                var newHtml;
                if(wordCount < 2){
                    // only one word
                    newHtml = theHtml;
                }
                else if(wordCount == 2){
                    // word count is 2...
                    newHtml = theWords[0]+" <span style='color: #000'>"+theWords[1]+"</span>";
                }
                else {
                    // add the first two words:
                    newHtml = theWords[0]+" "+theWords[1]+" <span style='color:#000'>";

                    // need to loop through the array now
                    for(var i = 2; i<wordCount; i++){
                        newHtml = newHtml+theWords[i];
                        if(i+1 < wordCount){
                            newHtml = newHtml+" ";
                        }
                    }

                    //end
                    newHtml = newHtml+"</span>";
                }
                jQuery(this).html(newHtml);
            });

        });
```

Which works quite well. But now I have a problem which is sometimes there is an `a` element or a `div` (for an inline editor if logged in as an admin) in the titles which is breaking this...

How would I get around this? I need to potentially get all the html from the header tag, strip the HTML tags, add the span around the latter part, then put the html back in!

Any ideas?

Thank you.

**Edit:**

This is what the problematic html looks like:

```
<h1 class="entry-title"><div data-type="input" data-post_id="12" class="fee-field fee-filter-the_title">Bristish Society of Blood and Marrow Transplantation</div></h1>
```

And like this:

```
<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="#" title="Permalink to About the Registry" rel="bookmark"><div data-type="input" data-post_id="62" class="fee-field fee-filter-the_title">About the Registry</div></a></h2>
```

But if not logged in as an administrator then the div's go away.

Comment: What does the HTML that's causing the problem look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey! Nice one, I think this is possible with regular expressions. I made a quick example for you, covering the a and the div for the biggest part. All spaces that are not meant as real whitespaces (in the tags) are replaced with symbols like `___` or `---`, which are changed back afterwards.
Take a look at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hXAu/1/)!

```
theHtml = theHtml.replace(/[\s]+\</gi,'<');
theHtml = theHtml.replace(/\s+[\'\"]/gi,'___');
theHtml = theHtml.replace(/[\'\"]\s+/gi,'---');
theHtml = theHtml.replace(/a\s/gi,'a_');
theHtml = theHtml.replace(/div\s/gi,'div_');
```

and backwards:

```
newHtml = newHtml.replace(/___/gi,' "');
newHtml = newHtml.replace(/---/gi,'" ');
newHtml = newHtml.replace(/div_/gi,'div ');
newHtml = newHtml.replace(/a_/gi,'a ');
```

***COMMENT*** after your edit

This will not work for the example h1 and h2 you posted. This is just an idea of how to approach this. I hope this will help you! Good luck!

***COMMENT2*** after my own edit ;-)

It *does* work, I just forgot to add case insensitivity and recursivity! It's just not finished yet. There are more checks needed such as `'` or `"` etc. [Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/6hXAu/2/), I hope this will get you on the right track.

Comment: Hey... this is brilliant! It got me to thinking though, if I use text() and then replaced the relevant words in the html() that would get around this problem! :) thanks for your help. replace() was the key! :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the jQuery [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function to strip out all the text within any particular H1, H2 tags etc. Other HTML inside these tags will be ignored.

But, i'm not sure how you will restore all the Inner HTML tags back.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jQuery's [wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) function?  I think it does what you're looking for in just one line.

```
$('h1, h2, h3').wrapInner('<span></span>');
```

Comment: the problem with that function is (as far as I can tell) it wraps ALL of the text inside it, whereas I only want all words after the first 1 or 2 wrapped with a span, if you see my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what class will be in the "inner" HTML element, you can just grab that.

```
var outer = $('.entry-title');
var html = html.find('.fee-field');

if(html === null){
    html = outer;
}

// html will either be your `h` element or your inner most element.
```